# Notepad++ Regular Expressions, find specific code in 170 files

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have 170 files which have something like this:

```
[color=#ffb300]Name[/color]
<?php include 'test.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
[color=#ffb300]Name2[/color]
<?php include 'test2.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
[color=#ffb300]Name3[/color]
<?php include 'test3.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
```

In every file I have different text here:

```
$boepsffhfu
```

And would like to replace everything to this code:

```
<?php
include 'hostsList.php';

foreach($hosts as $fileName => $bbCode) {
    echo $bbCode;
    include $fileName;
    echo $boepsffhfu;
}
?>
```

But we have to remember that in second code $boepsffhfu has to stay the same as was in that file. Sorry about my english, but I've been trying to sort this out for the last few hours and Im not able to do it. PS. I have installed addon multiline find and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** (Use Regular expression search mode)

Find: `include 'test[\d]{0,}.php'; echo "`

Replace with: `\ninclude 'hostsList.php';\n\nforeach\($hosts as $fileName => $bbCode\) {\n\techo $bbCode;\n\tinclude $fileName;\n\techo` (space character at end)

**Step 2:** (swap to Extended search mode for this one)

Find: `"; ?>`

Replace with: `;\n}\n?>`

Following these steps will turn this:

```
[color=#ffb300]Name[/color]
<?php include 'test.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
[color=#ffb300]Name2[/color]
<?php include 'test2.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
[color=#ffb300]Name3[/color]
<?php include 'test3.php'; echo "$boepsffhfu"; ?>
```

into this:

```
[color=#ffb300]Name[/color]
<?php 
include 'hostsList.php';

foreach($hosts as $fileName => $bbCode) {
    echo $bbCode;
    include $fileName;
    echo $boepsffhfu;
}
?>
[color=#ffb300]Name2[/color]
<?php 
include 'hostsList.php';

foreach($hosts as $fileName => $bbCode) {
    echo $bbCode;
    include $fileName;
    echo $boepsffhfu;
}
?>
[color=#ffb300]Name3[/color]
<?php 
include 'hostsList.php';

foreach($hosts as $fileName => $bbCode) {
    echo $bbCode;
    include $fileName;
    echo $boepsffhfu;
}
?>
```

If you want to keep the `"` marks around the text being echoed out, simply remove the `"` from each find command.